# What would be right place to put Categories under folder structure Xcode Project

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture

I have structured my project following MVC pattern so took Folders like

- Model
- View
- Controller
- Helpers
- Stores
- Resources

I am not sure **"Categories"** comes under which folder.

Comment: I prefer always to create it as a separate folder. Because you can have extension to viewControllers, views or even to your models. Other approach which I don't favor much is creating Extension as a subfolder in each folder which needs extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Category/Extension folder in top structure where-in the extension to classes that will be used throughout the app can be placed.

- Model
- View
- Controller
- Extensions

> For Instance: The extensions for UIFont, String, UIColor, UIButton are
>   something that will be of use across all the controllers. So these
>   extensions can all go under the top level Category/Extension folder.

Furthermore, it is best if the extension of a ViewController, AppDelegate are grouped together in a folder of it's own thereby improving the organisation and readability of folders and classes in it.

**For example the AppDelegate folder with extension will be something like this:**

```
AppDelegate     //folder
   -AppDelegate  //classes
   -AppDelegate+RootHandling
```